# How do you remove decorations/lines from picture in photoshop?

Tags: adobe-photoshop

[image]

like on this train how do you remove the decorative lines?

Comment: What decorative lines? The rails? The cable above? The pin striping on the train?

Answer (score 2):

Photoshop offers many tools to remove parts of an image, such as the clone stamp, patch tool, healing brush, spot healing brush, or content-aware fills. Using selections can help isolate areas you want to work with, and the dodge and burn tools can correct colors that might be out of place when you clone.

For this image, I'd probably stick with the clone stamp.

If you're new to Photoshop, you'll find that searching for tutorials using those terms will help you out a lot. The techniques aren't all that complex, they just have their own lingo and take some time to master.